# Install Opera Extension (Opera Blink) from installer

Tags: opera

In Chrome and Chromium I can install the extension
by creating the key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions\ in registry
with parameters "path" and "version"
In Opera Blink  I not see this ability (or it doesn't work)?
Does such ability exists?

Answer (score 1):

No, this functionality does not exist in Opera. (source: I'm PM for extensions at Opera Software).

Opera does have support for inline installation though: https://dev.opera.com/extensions/tut_inline_installation.html